# Problem in update query in JSP

Tags: java

all, i am writing an update query in jsp, but i am having a syntax error in it, can anybody help please. here is the query

```
<%
        HttpSession ss=request.getSession();
        String get_name=ss.getAttribute("key").toString().toUpperCase();
        if(get_name == null)
        {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
        else{
    %>

    <h2 align="left" style="color: white"><span style="background-color: blue">Welcome <%=get_name%></span></h2>
    <%
            }
            int i=0;
            String id=ss.getAttribute("id").toString();
            int id_num=Integer.parseInt(id);

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:database");
            Statement s=c.createStatement();

            String name_server=request.getParameter("name_ser");
            String details_ser=request.getParameter("details_ser");
            String date_ser=request.getParameter("date_ser");
            String status_ser=request.getParameter("status_ser");
            String subject_ser=request.getParameter("subject_ser");
            String cost_ser=request.getParameter("cost_ser");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name_server+","+details_ser+","+date_ser+","+status_ser+","+subject_ser+","+cost_ser+","+id_num+","+i);
            i=s.executeUpdate("update RECORD set NAME='"+name_server+"' ,DETAILS='"+details_ser+"' ,DATEE='"+date_ser+"' ,Status='"+status_ser+"' ,Subject='"+subject_ser+"' ,COST='"+cost_ser+"' where ID="+id_num+"");
            c.close();
            s.close();
            if(i>0)
            {
                response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
            }
    %>
```

Comment: Please paste the exception and the relevant parts of your JSP.  Tell us what DB are you using (date is probably a reserved word).  You should take care of SQL injections security issues, by the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got the problem, and able to execute the code, it was the problem related to Date :) thanks

Comment: I've included it as an anwser so you can mark it as accepted and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask, but you should know that this code is a very bad idea. Scriptlet code in JSPs is the wrong way to go.

I'd recommend that you learn JSTL and Model-2 MVC.  You should have servlets that do all the real work collaborating with JSPs.   The page should be doing nothing more than displaying what it's told to by the controller/servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Date is probably a reserved word in your database.

By the way, you should take care of SQL injections security issues and avoid mixing presentation and business logic.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no exception so I can say following might be reasons.

1. Your variable or variables has '  somewhere in string which is breaking the query.
2. Your variable or variables has invalid type of data.

There can be other reasons too but first think about them.

Answer (score -1):

this phrase

> where ID="+id_num+"");

needs a closing single quote like :

> where ID="+id_num+ "'");